# Stuck with wrong app uploaded as update in iTunes connect

Tags: ios, xcode, upload, binary, app-store-connect

I was updating my app to a version 2.0. So I created a new version in the "add new version tab" in iTunes connect. I uploaded my binary 2.0 and pressed the little plus button to add the new version to 2.0 build in iTunes connect.

However I released I need to change some extra things in the app so I went back and changed them. However now I cannot add upload this edited 2.0 version to iTunes connect as when I click upload it says that it is a redundant binary because a version 2.0 is already uploaded.

How can i fix this. I basically have the wrong 2.0 uploaded and can't swap it for the edited 2.0 and iTunes connect wont let me create a new version such as 2.1

Comment: Just increment the build number but leave the user-visible version at 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to increment your build number in Xcode. If you want to replace the same "editable" version in iTunes Connect, you can only do that by upload builds with "higher" build numbers.

[image]

So in your example this would be:

- **Version**: 2.0
- **Build**: 1.1 (Could be anything as long as the new build # > old build #)

Answer (score 2):

You need to update build number in target's **"General"** settings to upload new build with same version. Just increase the build number and you are good to go.